# Как записать HEX код в C# скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Вместо `Color.blue` записать hex код `#00e49d`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в текстовом варианте:

```
if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color != Color.Blue)
{
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
     {
         other.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.Blue
         Constrains();
         _currenGroundNumber++;
     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109938/407561

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Unity всегда использую такой метод:

```
private Color color;
void Start()
{
    ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#09FF0064", out color);
}
```

После запуска в color будет ARGB вариант цвета "#09FF0064".

Подробнее можно посмотреть в [официальной документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html)